# Why does mkvmerge not create two equal files after issuing the same command?

Tags: audio, video

I have a `.mkv` file which I want to delete one audio track from; let's call it `source.mkv`. The ID of the audio track I want to remove is `1`. So I issued this command:

```
mkvmerge -o out.mkv -a 2 source.mkv
```

After this I got curious and decided to repeat the same process to see if I got the same output file. So I issued the command:

```
mkvmerge -o out2.mkv -a 2 source.mkv
```

After doing this I calculated the `sha256` sum of both files and, to my surprise, they were different.

So my question is: why are the output files of the same command different?

My first thought is that maybe the video or audio track of the output files is loosing quality in the process, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

> My first thought is that maybe the video or audio track of the output files is loosing quality in the process, but I don't know why.

Probably timestamps. Try:

```
faketime @0 mkvmerge ...
```

Comment: Exactly — MKV files embed the "production date" in the DateUTC field (see [the specs](https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html) for details).

Comment: It didn't work. Still I get two different hashes. Any other idea?